# Convert factor variable of strings to list of integers using data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I'm trying to use data.table to recode a factor variable to integers. Given:

```
group
 005j         
 005j         
 0k16         
 0fff       
 0fff
```

I'd like to get a series of increasing integers representing the same grouping:

```
group   intCode
 005j      1   
 005j      1   
 0k16      2   
 0fff      3 
 0fff      3
```

I could do this with a loop but it would be extremely slow.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can simply use the `.GRP` symbol available in the `j` expression, with groups defined using `by = group`...

```
dt[ , intCode := .GRP , by = group ]
dt
#   group intCode
#1:  005j       1
#2:  005j       1
#3:  0k16       2
#4:  0fff       3
#5:  0fff       3
```

Quoting the help for `?data.table`...

> **`.GRP`** is an `integer`, `length` 1, containing a simple group counter. 1 for the 1st group, 2 for the 2nd, etc.